# Как вытащить файл из URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Находил в интернете несколько ответов, но мой случай не совсем стандартный так как в пути кроме ссылки на файл могут появляться дополнительные атрибуты, к тому же вложенность может меняться.
вот ссылка:

http://misite.ru/sites/default/files/styles/760_______/public/62242.jpg?itok=cQO_3H5R

Думаю надежный способ извлечения файла из строки следующий:

Файл всегда заканчивается на `.jpg`  мне как то извлечь часть строки, от `/`(не включая) до `.jpg` (включительно), которая и будет моим файлом `62242.jpg`.

но не знаю как это кодом реализовать.

Comment: Файл - редко заканчивается на `.jpg`, вы имеете в виду имя файла?

Comment: `url.split('/').pop().split('?')[0]`?

Comment: не совсем вас понял)) но какую часть из строки мне нужно извлечь я показал)

Comment: Когда мне нужно `вытащить файл из урл`, я выполняю http-запрос) Так понятнее?

Comment: да нет мне не нужно выполнять http-запрос только извлечь нужную часть из строки)

Comment: Ну так и напишите про `имя файла` в своём вопросе. Скрипт выше не выполняет вашей задачи?

Comment: да вроде должен) с массивами плохо знаком еще, я так понимаю, он даже, если в строке не будет этой ?itok=cQO_3H5R части, все равно сработает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делим по `/`, берём последнюю часть.
Делим по `?`, берём первый элемент результата.

При отсутствии `?query` части, `split` всё равно вернёт массив с одним элементом.

```js
[
'http://misite.ru/sites/default/files/styles/760_______/public/62242.jpg?itok=cQO_3H5R',
'http://misite.ru/sites/default/files/styles/760_______/public/62242.jpg',
].forEach(url => {
  console.log(url.split('/').pop().split('?')[0]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pos1 = pathstr.lastIndexOf("/"); 
var pos2 = pathstr.lastIndexOf(".jpg"); 
var filename = ""; 
if ( ( pos1 >= 0 ) && ( pos2 > 0 ) && ( pos2 > pos1 ) ) { 
  filename = pathstr.substring(pos1+1,pos2+3);
}
```